# Is there a limitation on how many dropdowns you can create using xlsx writer?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am using Xlsx writer, with a Pandas DF I have around 77000 rows, and I am attempting to update a column to have dropdown values using the `list` however when I tested with creating another column it worked and created the dropdown values.

But it did not set a default. So I have been attempting to loop the length of the column and create the data validation like so:

```
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
col_dropped_duplicates = data[col].drop_duplicates().copy()
default_vals = data[col].copy()
index_of_df_col = data.columns.get_loc(col)
xlsx_header_letter = self.excel_style(2, index_of_df_col)
worksheet.write(xlsx_header_letter + "1", col)
for header_num in range(2, len(default_vals) + 2):
    worksheet.data_validation(xlsx_header_letter + "2", {
        'validate': 'list',
        'source': col_dropped_duplicates.tolist()
    })
```

However the file saves successfully but when I open it is corrupted.